# The difference between adding a char to a string vs a string to char

Tags: c++, string, performance, stl

What is the performance difference between:

```
string s="";
//stk is std::stack<char>
 while(!stk.empty()){
            s+=stk.top();
            stk.pop();
        }            
        reverse(s.begin(),s.end());
```

and

```
 while(!stk.empty()){
            s=stk.top()+s;
            stk.pop();
        }
```

Why is the above more efficient? Can give an example if required.

[LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/)

Comment: When you measured, what was the performance difference?

Comment: I was solving a problem on leetcode. On using the second method, I got a TLE. It was resolved when I used the first one. Edit: it was logically correct and failed only for large inputs.

Comment: That might also be because the two things don't give identical results?

Comment: Those pieces of code are different.  They do not do the same thing.  You may want to erase this question, since at this point, it doesn't make a lot of sense given that the two pieces of code do vastly different things.

Comment: Actually It was inside a loop and I was getting my char from the stack. At the end of my loop, I reversed the string. So, logically it was the same. the string started from blank

Comment: Now the edit has made the question more confusing.

Comment: I'm sorry, please check the update

Comment: `s = stk.top() + s;` -- How many operations are being done here, as opposed to `s += stk.top();`?

Comment: Not sure about that.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the leetcode problem?

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/

Comment: Why are you using a stack and reversing a string to remove duplicates from a linked list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s+=stk.top()`, which in this case is equivalent to `s.push_back(stk.top())`, has amortized constant time complexity. `s=stk.top()+s`, is essentially equivalent to `s.insert(s.begin(), 1, stk.top())`, which is linear in the length of `s`.

Comment: Worse, because `s=stk.top()+s` has to create 2 entirely new copies (one to insert into, and then 1 on assignment), whereas `s+=stk.top()` doesn't.

Comment: `stk.top()+s` produces an rvalue, and since C++11 `s=stk.top()+s` will perform a move-assignment. Only 1 copy will ever be created.